# EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll not is getting added to the published folder only when I publish in RELEASE mode

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I know there is a problem with EF6 EntityFramework.SqlServer and included  `var type = typeof(System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices);` in context constructor. It works fine when i do publish in DEBUG mode.

Getting the below error only when I publish in RELEASE mode. The reason is `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` missing in the published folder. But, bin folder has EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll for both debug and release mode.

Error:

> The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'
>   could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is
>   used and that the assembly is available to the running application.

Why is it missing only when I publish using RELEASE mode?

Comment: In Solution Explorer, sSelect the reference to EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll and ensure that it's marked as "Copy to Output" in Release configuration and compare it to Debug.

Comment: Are you sure, you have the same database structure for debug and for release?

Comment: @libik: Yes, both has same structure. Also, verified both debug and release bin folders. It has EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll.

Comment: @Dai: Do you mean copy local? Because I don't "Copy to Output" property in my EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll properties.

Comment: Add attribute to your assembly to reference EntityFramework.SqlServer. For details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48318806/1881344

Comment: Related post - [Entity Framework Provider type could not be loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14033193/465053)

Answer (score 32):

Don't know why; but adding this method to your context will make your project copy the dll

```
private void FixEfProviderServicesProblem()
        {
            // The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer'
            // for the 'System.Data.SqlClient' ADO.NET provider could not be loaded. 
            // Make sure the provider assembly is available to the running application. 
            // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
            var instance = System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance;
        }
```

Tested and working
Reference: [Entity Framework Provider type could not be loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033193/entity-framework-provider-type-could-not-be-loaded)

Comment: This works.. Most likely because of this statement, the entityframework.sqlserver is "actually" used..

Comment: Confirmed fix to the problem.

Comment: What assemblies do you need to reference this? I tried adding System.Data and System.Data.Entity, but it still can't compile.

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same problem.

What happens is that this `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` is not referenced directly by your project, but internally by`EntityFramework.dll`.

Since we do not use any of this `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` in our code, the **Roslyn** compiler, applying some optimizations, understands that it does not need this component and then does not copy it to the`bin` folder and does not copy also for `Publish`.

What you need to do is create a reference to some object of this `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` anywhere in your code.

For example, I have a dependency injection container configuration class, where I configure my repositories and contexts, and I think it would be a good location. So I created a static property that I never use in any location, but it solves the problem:

```cs
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;

public class ContainerConfiguration
{
    // HACK: This code snippet ensures that the DLL (EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll)
    // not removed by compiler optimizer (csc.exe roslyn)
    public static SqlProviderServices EntitySqlServerHack => SqlProviderServices.Instance;

    public void ContainerConfiguration(IContainer container)
    {
        InternalConfigure(container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to add the missing reference is to add it directly in the .csproj file of your project. Just copy the EntityFramework reference, remove the publicKey entry and you're good to go