# Visual Studio building solution does not copy dll to bin folder, but building project does

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have a visual studio 2013 update 4.  I have a solution that includes multiple projects (all C#).

example:

- -MySolution

  -Webapi project ( references core project )

  -core project ( regular class library, contains nuget package for EntityFramework 6.1.2 )

If I build the solution and try to exec a webapi method it fails because EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll is not in the bin folder of the webapi project.

If however I build the core project alone, EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll is copied into the bin folder of the Webapi project and everything is fine.

Is there some bug or am I doing something wrong by building the solution and expecting the same result if I had built the projects in order?

It appears to be some Nuget oddity at first blush.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Consider posting your build output information.

Comment: If you're referencing the .dll directly, right click on the .dll->properties->Copy Always

Comment: I think you need to have a reference to the EF NuGet package from your webapi as well.

Comment: I may not be able to post build output due to business constraints.  I don't see any option for Copy Always, only Copy Local and that wouldn't copy from core to webapi in any case I don't think.  I don't think webapi should have a ref to EF, core is the dependency there, not EF.  Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: If the core project reference is a Project Reference, then WebApiProject will need to have an explicit dependency on EF 6.1.2. If you pull Core out and make its own nupkg, it will have a dependency on EF 6.1.2 which should get pulled in automatically when you `Install-Package -Id MyCore`

Comment: Related post - [EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll not is getting added to the published folder only when I publish in RELEASE mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25433298/465053)

Answer (score 1):

"When you don't use the referenced DLL in your code at all, it will ignore the CopyLocal and won't copy it to your output directory." says the following link:

[How does visual studio determine what to copy to the output directory with multi-project solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353617/how-does-visual-studio-determine-what-to-copy-to-the-output-directory-with-multi/2828191#2828191)

Facing same problem and keeping with this hint, I made a dummy invocation in my library that referenced EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll and the issue was resolved:

```
string result = System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.Char(65);
```

May be you should also give it a try.

Comment: Note: The dummy invocation is just for the compiler, you don't need to actually invoke this code at run time