# Entity Framework error: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following MVC project structure:

BLL

DAL

CommonClasses

Web

i'm using Entity Framework 6.0.2.  The web project has a reference to the BLL and CommonClasses project.  BLL has a reference to DAL and CommonClasses.  Both BLL and DAL also have references to EF 6.0.2, added via Nuget.  Anytime my code tries to do anything with Entity Framework I get the error below:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.

I'm a bit lost on what's happening.  I have checked and there is a reference to EntityFramework.SqlServer in the DAL and BLL projects.  All projects also have a reference to System.Data.

The app.config file in both the DAL and BLL proejcts has the below line:

```
  <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455747, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175713, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641435

Comment: http://robsneuron.blogspot.com/2013/11/entity-framework-upgrade-to-6.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` is in the application directory for `Web1` (i.e. in the `bin` folder).  It doesn't always get copied if the top-level executable/site doesn't have a direct dependency on this file.

Comment: Is there anyway to add in via Visual Studio to it's always there for anyone else who grabs the project?  I just manually copied it into the bin and it worked, but how to do it through VS?  If I try to add a reference to it in the project, i don't see EntityFramework.SqlServer in the search results.

Comment: The hackiest (TM) way to do it is doing something like this and add a reference into the project using EntityFramework, then it'll get included as a dependency in any downstream projects:

    internal static readonly Type SqlProviderServicesType = typeof(System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices);

Answer (score 1):

Please see my SO answer here, which references a blog that was very helpful. I had to do a couple of steps to get that DLL copied and loaded.

[Error: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641435/error-no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invarian/23329890#23329890)