# Namespace name 'SqlServer' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When trying to add the hack listed in this question:
[Entity Framework Provider type could not be loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033193/entity-framework-provider-type-could-not-be-loaded)
at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19130718/261405 ,
I kept getting this error:
*Namespace name 'SqlServer' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity*

Comment: Noticed this got a downvote. Maybe that's because it's not phrased as a question? I posted this as an "Answer your own question" because I wasted two hours trying to figure it out, and hoped to help someone else, and it wasn't a question at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get the error to go away after updating my projects from Entity Framework 6.0.2 to 6.1.0.

Basically did this for all projects:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
```

And it started magically working.
I hope this helps someone else avoid the frustration that I had.