# the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5, entity-framework-6

I am getting the following error whenever I try to run the ASP.NET web application from branch solution in TFS. I am not getting any compilation error.

My application has 3 branches in TFS and all of them are throwing the same issue.

[image]

Here is the environment information:
Visual Studio 2012, ASP.NET Web Application, Entity Framework 6 and IIS 7.5

Web.Config

```
 <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Did anyone faced this exception? Do you have any solution for this issue?

Comment: You have Nuget package restore enabled? Delete your bin folder and rebuild.

Comment: Yes, I have Nuget package restore enabled. I tried deleting the bin folder and rebuild, but still the issue is occurring.

Comment: What does your <entityFramework> section look like in web.config? Lot's of similar issues here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033193/entity-framework-provider-type-could-not-be-loaded

Comment: Updated the question with settings in web.config.

Comment: That matches mine. I would try some of the suggestions in the link.

Comment: Sure, I will try the suggestions in the link. Thanks.