# How do I solve The Entity Framework provider exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf, publish

I have published my WCF project onto a server, i have also published an MVC application onto the same box which consumes the WCF services.

When trying login on my MVC application, this uses a wcf service, but i get this exception on the browser,

> The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'
>   could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is
>   used and that the assembly is available to the running application.

This is an entity framework exception, but i assume since my project already references EF in the dev environment, after deploying the service project, the DLLs should contain the EF reference also but I am not sure why I am getting this error.

I can see this message because I turned on the `includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"`

Comment: installed from NuGet Package Manager cause not correctly installed in the project. try again PM> Install-Package EntityFramework

Comment: As i mentioned, this is not on my local machine, this is on my server where I dont have visual studio installed. This is a published application throwing this error, it works fine on my local machine. @NazmulHasan

Comment: Delete the bin folder and clean/rebuild your solution, as I've suggested in [my answer to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48541380/1639385).

Comment: Related post - [Entity Framework Provider type could not be loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14033193/465053)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

@FranciscoGoldenstein saying ! You don't need to install Entity Framework in your Console application or whatever, you just need to add a reference to the assembly EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll. You can copy this assembly from the Class Library project that uses Entity Framework to a LIB folder and add a reference to it.

In summary:

- Class Library application:

  - Install Entity Framework
  - Write your data layer code
  - app.config file has all the configuration related to Entity Framework except for the connection string.
- Create a Console, web or desktop application:

  - Add a reference to the first project.
  - Add a reference to EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll.
  - app.config/web.config has the connection string (remember that the name of the configuration entry has to be the same as the name of the DbContext class.

it is work for me ! I hope it helps.

also try this link [Entity Framework Provider type could not be loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033193/entity-framework-provider-type-could-not-be-loaded)

Comment: you are right, for some reason, the build was not adding that library when i publish it for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest trick to resolve this issue is to add the following line inside one of the classes in your EF project:

```
public class Blablabla
{
    private static string __hack = typeof(SqlProviderServices).ToString();

    // other class members as they were before.
}
```

This will force the build process to copy **EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll** to the `\bin` folder of any project that has references to the EF project.

No need to install EF nuget package or make an explicit reference to EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll in any downstream project.

Comment: This is a great trick and avoids having to manually add `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll`.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall Entity Framework nuget and just reinstall, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem

My problem was solved by doing the following:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is something silly, but for future reference:

In my case I was working with Unit Testing. I added the configuration to the app.config, but never install the Entity Framework to the Unit Test Project.
After installed, so far so good.