# Coded UI in Release definition (TFS) error with entity framework

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

When I run in local my test "coded UI" from visual studio 2015 enterprise they work correctly, but when I run them from a "release definition" (TFS Version 15.117.26714.0) I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded . Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application.

I do not understand it because I have reviewed the entity framework DLLs and they are in the Build:

- EntityFramework.dll
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll

In local works fine, it only happens in the release definition when you run them on a windows 2012 server.

If the "Coded UI" test does not go to database and therefore has no referenced "Entity Framework" it works correctly in the release definition.

Comment: Seems did not get the referenced packages correctly on build server during the build. Have you restored the packages (Add **Nuget Installer** step to restore )?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I solve The Entity Framework provider exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260473/how-do-i-solve-the-entity-framework-provider-exception)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Provider type could not be loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033193/entity-framework-provider-type-could-not-be-loaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Make sure you have installed the Vistual Studio on the build/test
  machine.
- Check your release definition, make sure your have added the **Nuget
  Installer** step to restore the packages.
- Uninstall Entity Framework nuget and just reinstall.
- Check if the `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` was missing for any
  referenced project. If it is, just add the nuget package to that
  project.
- Try installing the latest [EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) through Nuget for your
  projects, then try it again.

Reference this similar thread : [How do I solve The Entity Framework provider exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260473/how-do-i-solve-the-entity-framework-provider-exception)