# Azure SQL Database connection using Active Directory Integrated authentication fails to open

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, autocad-plugin

I'm attempting to connect to Azure SQL Database via Entity Framework with a connection string similar to this:

`Data Source=<server>.database.windows.net;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;Initial Catalog=<database>`

The connection attempt is made within the context of a hosted WPF form running inside AutoCAD 2018. The project is built using .NET Framework 4.6 and EF 6.1.3.

I'm encountering the following error:

`Unable to load adalsql.dll (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated). Error code: 0x2. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513072`

Unfortunately the help link doesn't lead to page that provides technical details for this issue. I haven't so far discovered anything on the web elucidating the root cause.

I've also tried this connection string:

`Server=tcp:<server>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<database>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<username>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Integrated"`

It was copied from the Azure portal's `ADO.NET (Active Directory integrated authentication)` section. However, with this connection string I get the following error `Cannot use 'Authentication=Active Directory Integrated' with 'User ID', 'UID', 'Password' or 'PWD' connection string keywords`

But it doesn't contain a password segment. And after removing the `User ID` segment, I still get the `Unable to load adalsql.dll ...` error.

Comment: Were u able to resolve this error? Pls let us know. As we are facing the same issue, it would help.

Comment: No, I never did it resolved. I ended up using SQL Server password authentication instead of AD authentication.

Comment: I'm using Powershell to connect to Azure SQL and facing the same issue. If I remove the password and UID I get 'WSTrust response does not have recognized SAML assertion'

Answer (score 0):

The connection string
`Server=<server>.database.windows.net,1433; Authentication=Active Directory Integrated; Initial Catalog=<database>;`
works if you follow this hack:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// HACK: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19130718/852956
    /// </summary>
    public void FixEfProviderServicesProblem() {
        //The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer'
        //for the 'System.Data.SqlClient' ADO.NET provider could not be loaded. 
        //Make sure the provider assembly is available to the running application. 
        //See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

        SqlProviderServices instance = SqlProviderServices.Instance;
    }
```