# Entity Frame Work always return null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, app-config

I'm created windows service where I have problem in calling query using entity frame-work inside this service, its always return null.

I tried to reinstall entity-framework package from NuGet but nothing happend.

this is my app.config file part:

```
<add name="GPSContext" connectionString="data source=server_name;initial catalog=dbName;user id=username;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and (

> The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded.

) run time error returned when I configured my entity-framework:

```
   <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  </configSections>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: Make sure you have the `EntityFramework` and `EntityFramework.SqlServer` references in your project (the calling assembly / runnable project)

Comment: Yes I checked it and I have "EntityFramework" and "EntityFramework.SqlServer" references in my project

Comment: You are sure that you did not add EF to a Library project and referencing it from another project?

Comment: When I added EF I added it from NuGet but when I configure it I copied code from another project you think is this the problem and if yes, how can I configure my EF in app.config file?

Thanks for help

Comment: If I need to use EF in a library I will add it using Nuget if I have a Calling Assembly lets say my WPF app i will also install EF using Nuget there to make sure it is all working correctly. But take a look at my answer it will probably fix your problems :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of things...

Make sure you have both `EntityFramework` and `EntityFramework.SqlServer` added to the references of the `calling assembly`.

If this will not fix your problem you can `delete the BIN folder` and try again.

If this still isn't working add the following code somewhere in your `calling assembly`

```
internal static class MissingDllHack
{
   // Must reference a type in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll so that this dll will be
   // included in the output folder of referencing projects without requiring a direct 
   // dependency on Entity Framework. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22315164/1141360.
   private static SqlProviderServices instance = SqlProviderServices.Instance;
}
```

the compiler sometimes removes the entityFramework.SqlServer.dll if its not referenced! You do not need to do anything with this code!