# Entity Framework 6 an Oracle

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am trying to use **Oracle** Database with **Entity Framework 6** (.net 4.8 and MVC5).

All the queries I try to perform make this exception:

> The store type 'text' could not be found in the OracleEFProvider provider manifest

An example:

```cs
try 
{
   using (SXEntities db = new SXEntities()) 
   {
      db.MyModel.ToList();
   }
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
   Log.Error(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this similiar post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815790/the-store-type-varchar100-could-not-be-found-in-the-sqlserver-provider-manif

Comment: Yes this is not the same problem, and I tried the solution but with no success