# AXIS : An error occurred when verifying security for the message

Tags: java, .net, web-services, apache-axis, axis

I am have an application with talks to client backend using webservices.
I have generated the java client using Eclipse and WSDL/XSD provided by cleints.

When I try to send a request to the backend I am seeing below exception.

```
     faultSubcode:
 faultString: An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
 faultActor:
 faultNode:
 faultDetail:
        {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
        at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
        at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:604)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1759)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2915)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:741)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1208)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:525)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:392)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
        at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
        at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
        at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
        at com.app.main.ws.BasicHttpBinding_SendMessage.sendMessage(BasicHttpBinding_SendMessage.java:201)
        at com.app.main.ws.OTPConnector.main(OTPConnector.java:43)

        {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:machine114

An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
        at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
        at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:604)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1759)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2915)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:741)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1208)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:525)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:392)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
        at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
        at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
        at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
        at com.app.main.ws.BasicHttpBinding_SendMessage.sendMessage(BasicHttpBinding_SendMessage.java:201)
        at com.app.main.ws.OTPConnector.main(OTPConnector.java:43)
```

On searching internet for this problem, it seems that this issue is relevant with application hitting webservices application based on Microsoft technologies and same is the case with my application.

Please anyone familiar with this issue provide knowledge on what might be going wrong here.

Thanks,

Comment: Is your client and the server running on the same machine ? If not check the date and time of both machines.

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA no the client and server are running on different machines in different time zones. Will the difference in time between both machine matter ? I need to be sure on this before I can reach clients.

Comment: Difference of the time zone does not matter but if there is a difference in the time, it should matter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765212/an-error-occurred-when-verifying-security-for-the-message Check the first answer.

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA yes I have checked that. Is there a way I can update some configuration on the client code which will ignore this time difference while sending request.

Comment: As per my knowledge, there is no way. Try to sync time(If it is possible). Exact problem may be different. I just gave a hunch.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue with a SOAP based web service. In our case, we were trying to send Basic Authentication as part of HTTP header. Changed it to send as part of SOAP header - it resolved the issue. Use a tool like SOAP UI