# "An error occurred when verifying security for the message" - WCF certificate-based authentication

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, wcf, client-certificates

I am attempting to set up cert-based client authentication in a WCF service. I am using .NET 4.7.2.

I am testing both the host app and the client on the same machine. The intended behaviour is that the client uses a cert retrieved from a machine store to authenticate against the service.

I can see that channelFactory does have the desired certificate set. I can see that it has a private key set, when I view it via certmgr. I can see that its root cert is in the machine's root store.

This is how the client connects:

```
EndpointIdentity identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("serviceDnsId");

EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new System.Uri("net.tcp://192.168.64.222:8747/blahblah"), identity, new AddressHeaderCollection());

Service = serviceChannelFactory.CreateChannel(address);

channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "e1f3bd637d26df83361865bd85d046006c868546");

channelFactory.CreateChannel(address)
```

This is how the service is set up:

```
            SecurityBindingElement security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateCertificateOverTransportBindingElement();    
            elements.Add(security);

            SslStreamSecurityBindingElement sslStreamSecurityBE = new SslStreamSecurityBindingElement();
            sslStreamSecurityBE.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;    
            elements.Add(sslStreamSecurityBE);

            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(elements);
 

            priceSinkSSLHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(IPriceSinkSSLService),
                binding,
                @"net.tcp://localhost:8747/blahblah/");
            setCertificate(serviceSSLHost);
            serviceSSLHost.Open();
```

I have removed a lot of code from both of the above that I understand to be unrelated.

The connection fails with the message "An error occurred when verifying security for the message".  I don't know what is wrong or how to investigate it.

As suggested by stuartd, I added a security audit behavior. I did this programmatically as follows:

```
            var audit = new ServiceSecurityAuditBehavior();
            audit.AuditLogLocation = AuditLogLocation.Application;
            audit.ServiceAuthorizationAuditLevel = AuditLevel.SuccessOrFailure;
            audit.MessageAuthenticationAuditLevel = AuditLevel.SuccessOrFailure;
            audit.SuppressAuditFailure = false;
            priceSinkSSLHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(audit);
```

If the security isn't set in the client, the following is logged:

> MessageSecurityException: Security processor was unable to find a
> security header in the message. This might be because the message is
> an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the
> communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured
> for security and the client is not using security.

If it is set as above, then nothing is logged and it doesn't connect.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765212/an-error-occurred-when-verifying-security-for-the-message

Comment: _"[You] are able to find out what actually went wrong behind the scenes by enabling a WCF feature called Service Security Audit. This is done by adding (and configuring) a line like this to the WCF behavior configuration on the server side"_ - from https://web.archive.org/web/20130703031304/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/urig/archive/2011/01/23/wcf-quot-an-error-occurred-when-verifying-security-for-the-message-quot-and-service-security-audit.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that. I don't think any of it is applicable to my particular issue.

Comment: Right, so you've added Service Security Audit ([this](https://intrepiddeveloper.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/security-event-logging-auditing/) is a better link) and looked in the application event log for the failure reason. So what is it?

Comment: Not yet - my previous comment was a response to your first link. I think I wrote it at the same time as your second comment... Thanks, the audit looks likely to help. I will update this when I have added it.

Comment: I've updated the post with the results of applying the security audit to the service.

Comment: You can try to read [this post](https://coderedirect.com/questions/392831/wcf-authentication-an-error-occurred-when-verifying-security-for-the-message) to find the solution.